# format date-times in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, datetime, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using FullCalendar and I'm trying to send start & end datetimes properly formatted to MySQL Database in order to update an event.

This is the relevant code:

First of all, when I log the *arg.event.start* variable I get this:

```
  eventChange: function(arg) {  
       console.log(arg.event.start);

//this is what I get:
Sat Nov 19 2022 11:00:00 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central)
```

Then if I try to parse it like this:

```
var theStart = FullCalendar.formatDate(arg.event.start, "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: context.cmdFormatter is not a function
at CmdFormatter.format (main.js:1549:28)
at DateEnv.format (main.js:4104:30)
at Object.formatDate (main.js:4288:24)
at Calendar.eventChange (calendario.jsp:78:30)
at Emitter.trigger (main.js:4850:25)
at EventDragging._this.handleDragEnd (main.js:11348:54)
at Emitter.trigger (main.js:4850:25)
at HitDragging.handleDragEnd (main.js:10893:31)
at Emitter.trigger (main.js:4850:25)
at FeaturefulElementDragging.stopDrag (main.js:10763:26)
```

and I get the same error if I try to do it like this (using "calendar" the FullCalendar object)

```
var theStart = calendar.formatDate(arg.event.start, "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

In case it helps, this is how the FullCalendar code starts:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: 'es',
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'addEventButton dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    ...
    ... 
    etc.
```

The JSON date-times from the events that FullCalendar loads are formatted like this and FullCalendar loads all events successfully:

```
"start":"2022-11-02 05:00:00.0","end":"2022-11-02 06:00:00.0"
```

I guess that FullCalendar somehow translate those date-times to some other format (the one above, including weekday, month with letters, GMT, timezone etc.) taken from my local settings. That's why I'd rather use FullCalendar formatter than a javascript formatter so my app will work in a computer with different locale settings.

Anyway, I've been struggling with this for some hours so any help will be really appreciated.

FullCalendar Version: v5.11.3

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-formatDate makes clear that the second argument to it should be an object containing some date-formatting settings described in more detail in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting, not a string. The latter article then goes onto explain that if you want to use a formatting string, that's only possible if you have enabled one of the supported date plugins - it's unclear if you've done that or not in your calendar instance.

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" it by using Event's *startStr* and *endStr* properties instead.

(I guess that's what they're for)

Thanks anyway.